# Setting background color distort the Table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a grouped table view on one of my view. And inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegator method I have set background color for each table cell as follows.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:221.0/255 green:241.0/255 blue:249.0/255 alpha:1.0];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Background color set without any problem. But problem occur in top and bottom cells. In top and bottom cells have curved edges. But when I add the background color it distort the edges. I have uploaded a print screen in such window.You can see the issue occure in the bottom cell where i have set the background color. Can some one please tell me how to solve this problem. [image]

Comment: Sorry.. for the delay. Now I have uploaded it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

not

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:color];
```

A UITableViewCell is a more complex object than an object with a contentView propretry.
You can find more about cell in [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell's clipsToBounds property to YES, that should make it respect rounded cell boundaries.